# The argument "plan_product" is required, but no definition was found

Tags: terraform

I am trying to provision both a Rocky VM (which costs $ per hour) and an Ubuntu VM (which doesn't)

Rocky VM requires the **plan block** nested in **resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine**

Ubuntu doesn't require the block

I'm getting the following error when running terraform plan:

```
Error: Missing required argument
│
│   on compute_lin_vm.tf line 43, in module "vm-jpdev":
│   43: module "vm-jpdev" {
│
│ The argument "plan_name" is required, but no definition was found.
╵
╷
│ Error: Missing required argument
│
│   on compute_lin_vm.tf line 43, in module "vm-jpdev":
│   43: module "vm-jpdev" {
│
│ The argument "plan_product" is required, but no definition was found.
╵
╷
│ Error: Missing required argument
│
│   on compute_lin_vm.tf line 43, in module "vm-jpdev":
│   43: module "vm-jpdev" {
│
│ The argument "plan_publisher" is required, but no definition was found.
```

Linux VMs modules block

```
module "vm-ansiblecontroller" {
  resource_group_name = module.rg-ansiblecontroller.resource_group_name
  location            = local.location
  linux_machine_name  = "linux-test1"
  tags                = var.tags

  nic_id = [module.vm-ansiblecontroller.nic_id]
  subnet_id = module.subnet-networkcore.subnet_id

  virtual_machine_size = "Standard_D2"

  admin_username       = "jpadmin"
  admin_ssh_public_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")

  source_image_publisher = "procomputers"
  source_image_offer     = "rocky-lnx-8-latest"
  source_image_sku       = "rocky-linux-8-latest"
  source_image_version   = "8.5.20220222"

  plan_name = "rocky-linux-8-latest"
  plan_product = "rocky-lnx-8-latest"
  plan_publisher = "procomputers"
  
  operating_system_disk_cache = "ReadWrite"
  operating_system_disk_type  = "Standard_LRS"

  ip_configuration_name         = "internal"
  private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"

  public_ip_allocation_method = "Static"
  public_ip_sku               = "Standard"

   depends_on = [
    module.rg-networkcore,
    module.vnet-networkcore,
    module.subnet-networkcore
  ]
}

module "vm-jpdev" {
  resource_group_name = module.rg-jpdev-vm.resource_group_name
  location            = local.location
  linux_machine_name  = "linux-test2"
  tags                = var.tags

  nic_id = [module.vm-jpdev.nic_id]
  subnet_id = module.subnet-networkcore.subnet_id

  virtual_machine_size = "Standard_D2"

  admin_username       = "jpadmin"
  admin_ssh_public_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")

  source_image_publisher = "Canonical"
  source_image_offer     = "UbuntuServer"
  source_image_sku       = "16.04-LTS"
  source_image_version   = "latest"

  operating_system_disk_cache = "ReadWrite"
  operating_system_disk_type  = "Standard_LRS"

  ip_configuration_name         = "internal"
  private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"

  public_ip_allocation_method = "Static"
  public_ip_sku               = "Standard"

}
```

modules/virtualmachine/linux/main.tf

```
# Linux Virtual Machine
resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "vm-linux" {

  name                = var.linux_machine_name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  tags                = var.tags

  size                            = var.virtual_machine_size
  admin_username                  = var.admin_username
  disable_password_authentication = true
  network_interface_ids           = var.nic_id

  admin_ssh_key {
    username   = var.admin_username
    public_key = var.admin_ssh_public_key
  }

  source_image_reference {

    publisher = var.source_image_publisher
    offer     = var.source_image_offer
    sku       = var.source_image_sku
    version   = var.source_image_version
  }

  # plan {
  #   name      = var.plan_name
  #   product   = var.plan_product
  #   publisher = var.plan_publisher
  # }

  dynamic "plan" {
    for_each = var.plan_product == "rocky-lnx-8-latest" ? [1] : []
    content {
      name      = var.plan_name
      product   = var.plan_product
      publisher = var.plan_publisher
    }
  }

  os_disk {
    caching              = var.operating_system_disk_cache
    storage_account_type = var.operating_system_disk_type
  }
}

# Network Interfaces for Linux VM
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic-linux" {
  name                = var.linux_machine_name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  tags                = var.tags

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = var.ip_configuration_name
    subnet_id                     = var.subnet_id
    private_ip_address_allocation = var.private_ip_address_allocation
    public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.pip-linux.id
  }
}
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "pip-linux" {
  name                = var.linux_machine_name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  tags                = var.tags

  allocation_method = var.public_ip_allocation_method
  sku               = var.public_ip_sku
}
```

modules/virtualmachine/linux/variables.tf

```
# VM Name
variable "linux_machine_name" {
  description = "Linux Virtual Machine Name - If left blank generated from metadata module"
  type        = string
  default     = ""
}

variable "resource_group_name" {
  description = "Resource group name"
  type        = string
}

variable "location" {
  description = "Azure region"
  type        = string
}

variable "tags" {
  description = "tags to be applied to resources"
  type        = map(string)
}

# VM Size
variable "virtual_machine_size" {
  description = "Instance size to be provisioned"
  type        = string
}

variable "admin_username" {
  description = "names to be applied to resources"
  type        = string
}

variable "admin_ssh_public_key" {
  description = "(Linux) Public SSH Key - Generated if left blank"
  type        = string
  default     = ""
  sensitive   = true
}

# Operating System
variable "source_image_publisher" {
  description = "Operating System Publisher"
  type        = string
}

variable "source_image_offer" {
  description = "Operating System Name"
  type        = string
}

variable "source_image_sku" {
  description = "Operating System SKU"
  type        = string
}

variable "source_image_version" {
  description = "Operating System Version"
  type        = string
  default     = "latest"
}

# Plan Block Variables
variable "plan_name" {
  description = "Plan Name"
  type        = string
}

variable "plan_product" {
  description = "Plan Product"
  type        = string
}

variable "plan_publisher" {
  description = "Plan Publisher"
  type        = string
}

# Operating System Disk
variable "operating_system_disk_cache" {
  description = "Type of caching to use on the OS disk - Options: None, ReadOnly or ReadWrite"
  type        = string
  default     = "ReadWrite"
}

variable "operating_system_disk_type" {
  description = "Type of storage account to use with the OS disk - Options: Standard_LRS, StandardSSD_LRS or Premium_LRS"
  type        = string
  default     = "StandardSSD_LRS"
}

variable "ip_configuration_name" {
  description = "ip configuration name"
  type        = string
  default     = ""
}

# Networking
variable "nic_id" {
  type        = list(string)
  description = "ID of the nic"
}

variable "subnet_id" {
  type        = string
  description = "ID of the subnet"
}

variable "private_ip_address_allocation" {
  type        = string
  description = "Private ip allocation method"
}

variable "public_ip_allocation_method" {
  type        = string
  description = "Public ip allocation method"
}

variable "public_ip_sku" {
  description = "SKU to be used with this public IP - Basic or Standard"
  type        = string
  default     = "Standard"
}
```

modules/virtualmachine/outputs.tf

```
    # Interface id
    output "nic_id" {
      description = "ids of the vm nics provisoned."
      value = azurerm_network_interface.nic-linux.id
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get these errors, because these variables are marked as required. You can change that by giving them a **default value**:

```
# Plan Block Variables
variable "plan_name" {
  description = "Plan Name"
  type        = string
  default     = ""
}

variable "plan_product" {
  description = "Plan Product"
  type        = string
  default     = ""
}

variable "plan_publisher" {
  description = "Plan Publisher"
  type        = string
  default     = ""
}
```